# Htaccess file, Redirect Old Pattern without Query to New Pattern with Query String

Tags: .htaccess

I am moving website to a new technology platform.

Anyway, I need to redirect some old patterns, to a new pattern with a query string:

Something like this:

`www.example.com/DirA/DirB/OldPage-123456`

needs to become

`www.example.com/search?q=OldPage`

So I need to drop the inner directories, drop the trailing number (which is a database primary key in the old site) and redirect the portion before the primary key into a new search page with a search parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^DirA/DirB/OldPage-123456/(.*)$ /search?q=OldPage/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

or this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^DirA/DirB/(.*)$ /search?q=/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Yep that works, although I am not sure about the forward slash before $1 in the last line in last method.

Comment: The forward slash means everything after that is not changed and remain as is original. Does that make sense? But in general that was more or less a starting point and not exact solution as I do not know all the pages you need the rule to apply to. Cheers